# The Discord music bot does not play music in the Docker container

Tags: docker, discord.js, dockerfile, audio-player, distube

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to deploy a Discord music bot on a remote Ubuntu Linux server in a Docker container.

The problem is that when the bot is launched in the container, the music does not play, while other parts of the bot that are not related to music playback work fine; at the same time, if the bot is launched outside the Docker container environment, the bot works fine and the music is played.

The bot's behavior when requesting music playback when it is operating in a container is as follows: the bot displays a message that it has found a song and that it starts playing it, and immediately thereafter displays a message that the song has finished playing.

I guess the problem lies in my `Dockerfile`, or in how I run the image.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

ENV WORK_FOLDER='/usr/MyBot'

WORKDIR ${WORK_FOLDER}
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "tsconfig.json", "./"]
COPY src ./src

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g typescript
RUN npm run build
COPY . .

CMD ["node", "./dist/index" ]
```

I'm building an image with the command:

```
docker build -t mybot .
```

And I launch the container as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --restart=always --name=mybot mybot
```

The bot is written in TypeScript using the library `discord.js`. To play music, the bot uses the library `distube.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. In my case, the problem was that my Docker was configured to create Alpine images. As far as I understand, the Alpine image is stripped down for better performance, and I assume that the Alpine image simply did not have the libraries necessary for the music part of the bot to work correctly.

My solution was to completely reinstall Docker according to the instructions for Ubuntu from the [official Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/). I also needed to change the version of Nodejs used in the image from `node:lts-alpine` to `node:18.12`, and I also changed the port used by my image from `8080` to `3000`.

Ultimately, my `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:18.12

ENV WORK_FOLDER='/usr/MyBot'

WORKDIR ${WORK_FOLDER}
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "tsconfig.json", "./"]
COPY src ./src

RUN npm install npm -g
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g typescript
RUN npm run build
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "./dist/index" ]
```

It took me a long time to find a solution to this problem, so I'm sharing with you one of the ways to check which image your Docker is configured for: just call the batch manager when building the image in your `Dockerfile`. `RUN apk update` will work for Alpine, and `RUN apt-get update` for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If your Docker host is a Linux machine, you should be able to start your container with `docker run -d -p 80:80 --restart=always --name=mybot mybot --device /dev/snd` in order to allow the Docker container to access the audio device of the host.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it didn't help. The behavior of the bot has not changed.