# Track duration is 00:00 ( discord.js, distube )

Tags: docker, discord, discord.js, dockerfile, distube

I was make a music bot using Distube and Discord.js

When i run on **Powershell** it works properly and can play music normally. But when I create the Image and hang the Container with Docker the bot can't get that song and show the duration as 00:00 and skip current track

Here is screenshot

[image]

## package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "graffity",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Jamien#0378",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.7.0",
    "@discordjs/voice": "^0.16.0",
    "@distube/soundcloud": "^1.3.2",
    "@distube/spotify": "^1.5.1",
    "@distube/yt-dlp": "^0.0.2",
    "@distube/ytdl-core": "^4.11.11",
    "@sapphire/utilities": "^3.12.0",
    "ascii-table": "^0.0.9",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "common-tags": "^1.8.2",
    "cpu-stat": "^2.0.1",
    "discord.js": "^13.16.0",
    "distube": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.1",
    "gradient-string": "^2.0.2",
    "libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.11",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "spotify-url-info": "^3.2.5"
  }
}
```

## Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app/

COPY package*.js ./

COPY ./ ./

RUN apk add --update python3 make g++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm rebuild

RUN npm install

CMD ["node", "shard.js"]
```

I changed to distube@3.3.4 and older versions but still the same

Comment: Does this helps you to resolve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347549/the-discord-music-bot-does-not-play-music-in-the-docker-container

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC thanks for link but everything just be worse